# env Variable Not working for firebase at React js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, config

I am tried to get the firebase config file using env.process. If I use directly the config info. its working well...

**Firebase.init.js**

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export default auth;
```

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=*********************
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN=**************************
REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID=****************
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET=***********************
REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=****************
REACT_APP_APP_ID=***************************
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY}`,
authDomain: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}`,
projectId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}`,
storageBucket: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET}`,
messagingSenderId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}`,
appId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID}`,
measurementId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID}` };
```